# How to put closing tag like<input/> in django form "input" tag?

Tags: django, reactjs

// I am coding my program in django with mixing react as well. When I created form in django, it doesn't by default put closing tag "/>" in input tag. so it it producing closing tag error in react console.How to solve it.here is my code

```
//forms.py
class SignUpForm(forms.Form):
    phone_email = forms.CharField()


//views.py
def sign_up(request):
    form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'account/sign_up.html', {"form": form})


//sign_up.html
 class Sign_up extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <form method="post" action="">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form.as_p }}
            </form>
        )
    }
}


//error


  //syntaxError: embedded: Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for <input>      (18:143) 16 | <form method="post" action=""> 17 | <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="UWBCh291YmYuTNYqk9OKsihm7y1JtrFvgRNNoknJY6Be3fH6ov7uytcgcfPC6Yao"> > 18 | <p><label for="id_phone_email">Phone email:</label> <input type="text" name="phone_email" required id="id_phone_email"></p>
```

Comment: I think you are doing it correct. Can you post the html that it produced, not just the JSX error. The file that is used to render the input is in path <python-site-packages>/django/forms/widgets/input.html if you want look into it.

Comment: actually,the html code is not rendered in the browser, the inspection section just shows the javascript code written in the script tag.

Comment: You could also omit the JSX stuff first in the sign_up.html to see if it produces correct html that way. Then, adding the React.Component would indicate the problem being in the React part.